# Recognition of USB drive

Tags: ubuntu, usb, usb-flash-drive, phone

I have a Motorola phone, with a MicroSD slot, which my Ubuntu machine does not recognize as a USB drive.

It does know there is something there since

- It automatically charges my phone whenever I connect it.
- using the command `lsusb` shows it as "Motorola PCS"

Is there a way to tell Ubuntu/Linux that the connected hardware is a disk drive?

Comment: I have same issue now. It shows as motorola pcs. Did you fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You probably have the phone in "Data Connection" or "USB Printing" mode instead of "Memory Card" mode. Go to USB Settings (in Settings | Connection on my phone) and change it.

Comment: It has Settings > Connection > USB Setting, in which you can choose between "USB Drive" and "Modem/COM".  Neither works in my Ubuntu box.

Answer (score 3):

Is there an option on the phone to turn on USB Drive mode? My phone(Motorola Rival) will not appear on my windows machine until I turn this setting on.

I found it under Menu -> Settings & Tools -> USB Mode.

Comment: Yes, but no luck.  It does work on Windows with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

You first mount it on Windows.
Do not Unplug the Phone and Then reboot the PC to Linux (I am Assuming you have dual Boot Windows/Linux)
Now when Linux Starts Open the terminal type the following Commands one by one and post all the outputs here.
`sudo fdisk -l`, 
`lsusb`, 
`dmesg` 
If some command requires root permission run that with sudo

Comment: Sorry, I've been Windows free (at home) for a while.  But I will try and run those commands.